# How do I list word count in multiple files?

Tags: command-line, bash

Say I need to find out how many words are in each file that has the word 'work' in its name.

I know that to find files with 'work' in the name, it would be `ls work`. And to figure out the number of words in a file it would be `wc -w`.

However I tried the following and it seems to be just displaying the number of files, not the number of words combined in all files (which I need):

```
ls work | wc -w
```

So say if there are 14 files that have 'work' in the name, it would display 14, not the number of words.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The syntax is `wc -w [FILE]`. If you don't use FILE but pipe in the output of `ls work` it will only count what it will read on stdin.

You need to pipe in the text itself:

```
cat *work* | wc -w
```

Alternative you could execute `wc` with `find -exec`. But be aware that this could show multiple "total" sums as `find` will call `wc` multiple times if there are lots of files.

```
find ./ -type f -name "*work*" -exec wc -w {} +
```

Comment: I used the `find` command to also be able to sum up the count of lines by using `wc -l`. Amazing!

Answer (score 4):

You can run `wc` with multiple files and then use shell built-in `*` which adds every non hidden files in working directory to `wc`'s parameters.

```
wc -w *work*
```

Comment: If a directory's name contain `work` then this will show the output along with an error..a hack will be to redirect the STDERR `2>/dev/null`..although you should use something like `find` to get only the files..

Comment: If the shell globs are not sufficient to locate the desired files (e.g. they're in deeply nested directories), you can also run `find` and pass the result to `wc`, like this: `wc --words $(find . -type f -name '*work*')`.

Answer (score 1):

There are some good answers here but for this I like to use:

```
ls | grep work | xargs wc -w
```